# Hibernate save new entry with ManyToOne annotation

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-one

I have the problem with deeply understand the save new entry with ManyToOne annotation.

I have two table:

1) UserGroup

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usergroup")
public class UserGroup{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userGroup",
            cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users= new ArrayList<>();

    //constructor, getter and setter
```

2) User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserGroup userGroup;
```

And the first table - UserGroup - was initialized with data. It is very important. I would like to connect that information when created new entry for User.

So User has data, f.e.

```
select * from usergroup;

id  name
1   name1
2   name2
3   name3
```

I created UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

And it is problematic part!

I would like add new User giving -> name and id user group.

Service:

```
@Override
@Transactional
    public void create(String name, Long groupId) {
        UserGroup userGroup = userGroupRepository.getOne(groupId);
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setUserGroup(userGroup)
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Where is the problem?

-> id for new user is null;
-> error: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [unique]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

It is the proper way to save new entry with connect to exist entry? I mean, I should find by id exists entry and set to new one?

Thank you for advice!

Comment: Is your service transactional? i.e. have you added the `@Transactional` annotation at class or method level?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the `@ManyToOne` annotation, you should be able to create a `User` on its own without a problem.

Comment: Yes, it is. Has annotation `@Service` and `@Transactional` from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

Comment: That line is working perfectly. `userGroup` was found corectly. The problem is with id with `userRepository.save`.

Comment: `id for new user is null`. So issue is with user Id and not Fk to user group?? What is the database?

Comment: It is the MySQL database. There is FK. `user_group_id` is connected with id in `UserGroup` table.

Comment: The error **id for new user is null**  indicates the issue is with ID and not the relationship. Why don't you enable SQL logging and post the full stack trace here to clarify the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both entities update as below.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id") //removed attributes unique = true, nullable = false
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

By specifying `nullable = false,` Hibernate is checking the ID is not null **before** writing to the database. However with `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, the ID will only be set after the database write, hence the error.

Comment: It is the solution! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem isn't the ManyToOne relation itself but the User's id generation. With `GenerationType.IDENTITY` you should provide an identifier for every User you'll save (I'm not seeing that part in the portion of code you provided) unless the database has an internal id generation (like serial in postgres).

As for the way to save entries connected to other existing entries what you are doing should works fine. Another approach could be to initialize the UserGroup by only setting a known id without to load it from the database. Of course, you'll face a reference error if the id isn't valid.

Comment: After added `user.setId(-1L);` the error is that same.